# Why collations results are empty in Solr spell checking

Tags: java, solr, spell-checking

I have configured a Solr spellchecking comoponent using IndexBasedSpellChecker with a core containing country names:

```
<searchComponent name="indexBasedSpellCheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker"> 
      <str name="name">indexBasedSpellCheck</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str> 
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./indexspellchecker</str> 
      <str name="field">name</str> 
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str> 
      <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevensteinDistance</str> 
      <str name="accuracy">0.5</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

And a request handler for spellchecking:

```
<requestHandler name="/index-spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">idxBasedSpellCheck</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components"> 
      <str>indexBasedSpellCheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

When I request :

`curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/index-spell?indent=on&spellcheck.q=tanaz&wt=json&spellcheck.collate=true'`

I get results in the suggestions like :

```
 "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "tanaz",{
        "numFound":3,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":5,
        "origFreq":0,
        "suggestion":[{
            "word":"canada",
            "freq":1},
          {
            "word":"panama",
            "freq":1},
          {
            "word":"tanzania",
            "freq":1}]}],
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":[]}
```

Why are my collations empty? I have spellcheck.collate=true in my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `df` (default field) parameter in your request.
  Add `df=name` in you request:

http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/index-spell?indent=on&spellcheck.q=tanaz&wt=json&spellcheck.collate=true&df=name

You also can configure this in your request handler defaults, so you don't need to send this in request.

```
<requestHandler name="/index-spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
       ...
      <str name="df">name</str>
       ...
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components"> 
      <str>idxBasedSpellCheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```